# rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms error

Tags: ros, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i run the command "rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:=/dev/ttyS0" on the Pioneer Powerbot,the terminal shows the error,and i had tried a lot of solutions on the internet,but those did not work.So hope your advice!
note:ROS electric ;Ubuntu 11.10

```
root@ubuntu:~# rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms _port:=/dev/ttyS0
    *** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
    Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyS0
        Device opened!
    Attempting to start buffer monitor...
        Buffer monitor started!
    Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Failed to set requested baud rate...
    Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
        Checking 19200bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 38400bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 500Kbps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS::Initialize: failed to detect baud rate!
[ERROR] [1346919668.935157216]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43195/rosrun-sicktoolbox_wrapper-sicklms-error/) by [Ocean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2058/ocean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-09**:
Are you using the correct device path? What does ls /dev/ttyS* give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is the fact that the laser takes its time when starting up. You need to set a [30 second delay](http://answers.ros.org/question/38472/sick-lms200-on-ros-electric/)...

If you need further assistance, don't hesitate to ask.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fábio Silveira Vidal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3907/f%C3%A1bio-silveira-vidal/) on 2013-06-25**:
Please, how to set delay to 30 seconds? Thanks.

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2017-06-06**:
Hi, @allenh1 I m getting error as shown here ? You know how to solve ? http://answers.ros.org/question/263224/initialize-failed-with-sick-lms-5xx/